# postgres arr_agg equivalent in sqlite3

Tags: sql, postgresql, sqlite

I want to convert a bellow query into sqlite3

```sql
    select
      (array_agg(
          json_build_array(timestamp, strike, expiry, volume, close, symbol,oi) order by timestamp desc
      ))[1] as data
    from
      one_min_datrue
    where
      symbol = 'symbol'
      AND INSTRUMENT IN ( 'type' )
      AND timestamp <= '2023-08-23 09:15:00'
      and expiry >= '2021-05-28'::date
    group by
      full_symbol, strike order by strike asc;
  )";
```

I have tried this but don't know how to sort

```sql
select
      json_extract(json_group_array(json_array(timestamp, strike, expiry, volume, close, symbol,oi)), '$[1]) as data
    from
      one_min_datrue
    where
      symbol = 'NIFTY'
      AND INSTRUMENT IN ( 'PE' )
      AND timestamp <= '2023-08-23 09:15:00'
      and expiry >= '2021-05-28'
    group by
      full_symbol, strike order by strike asc;
```

It is also okay to return in a rows rather than JSON (preferred),
Here is [playground](https://sqlime.org/#deta:729pxag8i7ee) I tried Thanks :)

Comment: can you kame a fidlle for both https://dbfiddle.uk/